# How to make Eclipse IDE to show Japanese/Chinese in bigger font

Tags: windows, eclipse, fonts, font-size

How to make Eclipse IDE to show Japanese/Chinese in bigger font?

Example. In Eclipse IDE

[image]

The same text copied to Outlook

[image]

That is Chinese characters are too small to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the font of all basic text to Courier New.

Eclipse -> Preference > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font.

Reference:
https://www.programering.com/a/MDMyQTMwATk.html

Answer (score 1):

1. In Project Explorer -> Right click on project folder -> go to "Properties"
2. In "Text File Encoding" manually type **SJIS** or **Shift-JIS**
3. apply
4. Done

Answer (score 0):

Font for Chinese in Eclipse
e.g. get YaHei.Consolas.1.12.ttf file and put in C:\Windows\Fonts\

Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts, open the Basic, double-click the “Text Font”, and then select font: ” YaHei Consolas Hybrid”

https://eclipse-china.github.io/2013/05/29/font-for-chinese.html

The font is on https://github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/blob/master/Fonts/YaHei.Consolas.1.12.ttf